# Eleventy website images disappear when deployed to Vercel

Tags: vercel, eleventy

I have a /src folder and Eleventy serves up the images into /_site folder.

On my localhost I'm using the image route: static/img/imagename.png and it works when loading onto the localhost.

However the image disappears when being deployed to Vercel. Wondering what the file route of my image should be.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your `_site` folder? There's not really enough information to determine what's going on.

Comment: Hey, here's the link to my github repo:

https://github.com/dulzorigo/dul-netlify-blog/tree/master